# Is it safe to join "pg_locks" table in production code?

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, locking

I have a queue-like table `t1` holding timestamp-ordered data. One of its columns is foreign key `ext_id`. I have a number of workers that process rows from `t1` and remove them after their job is done. Outcome of the process is upserting rows to another table `t2`. `t2` also references `ext_id`, but in this case relation is unique: if row pointing to the particular `ext_id` already exist I want to update it instead of inserting.

As long as single worker is processing the data task is fairly simple. When multiple workers are brought into play `SKIP LOCKED` clause comes to the rescue: each thread locks the row that it is processing and makes it invisible to other threads. `SKIP LOCKED` clause guarantees that threads are not interfering with each other in terms of source table `t1`. The problem is, that they can still try simultaneously insert rows into table `t2`. Since there is uniqueness constraint on `t2` this can yield error if multiple workers select `t1` rows sharing `ext_id`. Since constraint raises error I can simply retry processing of a particular row, but then I lose the guarantee of processing order (not to mention that exception-based flow control feels like serious anti-pattern).

I considered adding auxiliary "synchronization" table (lets call it `sync`), that would hold entry for each `ext_id` being currently processed. The processing becomes more complicated then: I need to commit `sync` row insertion before actually start processing, so that other threads can use this information to select `t1` rows that are safe to process. `t1` row selection can join the auxiliary table and match first row that has `ext_id` not present in `sync` table. It is still possible that concurrent threads will select consecutive rows and try inserting synchronization rows pointing to the same `ext_id`. If it happens I need to retry `t1` row selection.

Second approach solves concurrent processing of conflicting `t1` rows and guarantees that the row order is maintained (within partitions defined by `ext_id` values). What it fails to solve is dirty flow control structure based on failed insertions.

PostgreSQL provides advisory locks mechanism, which allows building of application-specific custom synchronization logic.

Quote from [explicit locking documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS):

> For example, a common use of advisory locks is to emulate pessimistic locking strategies typical of so-called “flat file” data management systems. While a flag stored in a table could be used for the same purpose, advisory locks are faster, avoid table bloat, and are automatically cleaned up by the server at the end of the session.

Usage of advisory locks solves exactly this problem and according to the documentation should yield better performance. When a process selects a row, it also obtains advisory lock parametrized with `ext_id`. If another process tries to select conflicting row, it will have to wait until the other lock is released.

This is much better, but in some cases it will prohibit subset of workers from performing their tasks simultaneously and make them wait to perform tasks in a sequence. What those workers could do instead of waiting is to try fetching another row: something that `sync`-based solution solved by excluding `t1` rows using outer join.

After this lengthy introduction, finally, the question:

Existing advisory locks can be inspected by querying `pg_locks` view. This view can be joined as a regular relation within queries. It is tempting to join it while fetching next `t1` row, to exclude rows that are currently unprocessable due to existing lock. Since `pg_locks` is not regular table I have some doubts if this approach is safe.

Is it?